# How load data from database to my input text after doing search/query

Tags: php, html

How can I load my database query to my input types like text and radio

Comment: Hi! This question is way too broad to answer. Could you please provide some examples of what you have already tried?

Comment: Well, I have a search input text and already do query but not sure how it will automatically place all data in all input types based on that id.

Comment: Please update you question to show the code you have already written, otherwise it's very hard for us to help you out.

Comment: Is there a way here I can upload a screenshot?

Comment: Do you mean dynamically set the value of input based on your database query?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

Is this what youre looking for?:

```
<?php
$query = "input query here, make sure it outputs 1 record";

//$con is connection variable
$stm = $con->prepare($query);
$stm->execute();
$result = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

//data from database
foreach ($result as $res) {
    $data = $res->data
}
?>

<input type="text" value="$data">
```

Comment: Actually, I think you are getting my point. However, what if the input types are there already and I have input text that when I click the search button it will load the data on my input types?

Comment: I have two options or radio basically for choices, one for new client and two for update. When I select new, I need to fill it out while for update I will key in client id and it should populate my input type(text)/radio etc.

Comment: I'm really sorry I knew to html/php/script and trying to learn day by day but this actually made me think